# CTA label for mobile reporting page

Tags: interface, copywriting

I'm putting together a simple website that allows users to view football-related reports. Users are able to select from 4 report types (player, team, league, country). Depending on which report type is selected, an additional dropdown is displayed which features specific options. The user can also select a date range (e.g. Last 7 days).

On the desktop site, all these options are visible. However, on mobile, these options are hidden in a slide-out drawer and is revealed when a user clicks a CTA. My question is, in this context, is the word **filters** a suitable label for this CTA?

I'm slightly hesitant as the report type dropdown doesn't feel like a filter.

Comment: How about showing `Filter by : Type` . Ex: `Filter by : Player` with a filter icon.

Comment: you say the dropdown features specific options. are those options filtering the results/items of the page?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a sticky / fixed CTA to call the slide-out drawer. How about showing the label text as

[`Filter by : default type ] [filter icon`]

[image]